# Discord.js - DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body embed.fields[0].value: This field is required Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

i have been trying to make an order command for my discord.js bot when someone uses the command it doesn't respond and says this error in the console "This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason:
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embed.fields[0].value: This field is required" however i have been trying to fix it but i can't see whats wrong with the code the code for the command is

````
const colors = require("colors");


function generateID() {
    let ticketGen = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".split("");
    let ticketStr = "";

    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        ticketStr += ticketGen[Math.floor(Math.random() * ticketGen.length)];
    }

    return ticketStr;
}

exports.id = "order";

exports.onLoad = api => {
    api.commands.add("order", (msg) => {
        // The order.
        let order = msg.content.substring(8);
        let customer = msg.author.id

        fsn.readJSON("./blacklist.json").then((blacklistDB) => {
            let entry = blacklistDB[msg.guild.id];
            
            // Checks is server is blacklisted or not.
            if(entry === undefined) {
                // Gets ticket ID.
                const ticketID = generateID();
        
                

                // Sends ticket information to tickets channel.
                api.client.guilds.get("745409671430668389").channels.get("746423099871985755").send({embed: {
                    color: 0xFFFFFF,
                    title: msg.author.username,
                    fields: [{
                        name: "Order Description",
                        value: order,
                    }, {
                        name: "Order ID",
                        value: ticketID,
                    }, {
                        name: "Order Status",
                        value: ticketID,
                    }],
                    timestamp: new Date(),
                    footer: {
                        text: `From ${msg.guild} (${msg.guild.id})`
                    }
                }}).then((m) => {
                    m = m.id;
        
                    // Sets ticket info.
                    fsn.readJSON("./orders.json").then(orderDB => {
                        // Set JSON information.
                        if (!orderDB[ticketID]) orderDB[ticketID] = {
                            "orderID": ticketID,
                            "userID": msg.author.id,
                            "guildID": msg.guild.id,
                            "channelID": msg.channel.id,
                            "order": order,
                            "status": "Unclaimed",
                            "ticketChannelMessageID": m
                        };
            
                        // Write JSON information.
                        fsn.writeJSON("./orders.json", orderDB, {
                            replacer: null,
                            spaces: 4
                        }).then(() => {
                            // Sends an embed to the customer.
                            msg.channel.send("Thanks for ordering! Your order will be delivered soon, Order ID: `\`${ticketID}\``");
                                
                            
            
                            // Logs in console.
                            console.log(colors.green(`${msg.author.username} ordered "${order}" in ${msg.guild.name} (${msg.guild.id}) in ${msg.channel.name} (${msg.channel.id}).`));
                        }).catch((err) => {
                            if(err) {
                                msg.reply(`There was a database error! Show the following message to a developer: \`\`\`${err}\`\`\``);
                                console.log(colors.red(`Error in order ${ticketID}: ${err}`));
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            }else {
                msg.reply("This server is currently blacklisted.");
            }
        });
    });
};```
````

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow! It simply means that there's no `value` in `fields[0]`. Try this:

```js
fields: [{
  name: "Order Description",
  value: order || "None", // Returns None if no order
}, {
  name: "Order ID",
  value: ticketID,
}, {
  name: "Order Status",
  value: ticketID",
}],
```

A better solution is to check if all the needed variables are what you expect. For example you could add this before your code:

```js
if (!order) return msg.reply("No order found.");
```